# Ask Different should have the correct favicon

Tags: bug, support, status-completed

Ask Different has a nice style, but the favicon is still the old sketchy-style. That should be replaced. It's OK on chat and meta.

Comment: I see the favicons (blue for Ask Different, grey for Ask Different meta) and so have flagged the question for tagging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to hard reload (Shift and reload button) the following link:

http://sstatic.net/apple/img/favicon.ico

For the meta site it's:

http://sstatic.net/applemeta/img/favicon.ico

Comment: Thanks, it's OK now. But I'm sure I didn't visit this site earlier…

Comment: @Nyu It's possible that the StackExchange dropdown box showed the Apple.se favicon to you before, without you visiting this site. I'm glad it's working for ya now.